# Kill only the currently focused window without killing others running under the same PID

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to write a function that kills the currently focused window in c++ using the windows API. What I have so far works fine for applications that open new windows in a different process each time. This is obvious by looking at the code. The problem is when the application opens multiple windows under the same PID an example being notepad as illustrated in screenshot below:[image]

My question thus becomes: How can I kill only the focused window without killing others with the same PID.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
void kill_foucused_window()
{
    HWND focused = GetForegroundWindow();
    DWORD procID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(focused, &procID);
    HANDLE procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, procID);
    TerminateProcess(procHandle, 0);
    CloseHandle(procHandle);
}
```

Comment: you nothing have at the moment, because you kill process

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Externally, you can kill a thread or a process (if you have adequate permissions), but you can't kill a window that you don't own. Only the thread that created the window can destroy the window.

Externally, all you can do is request the window to close itself (ie, send it a [`WM_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) messsage) and hope the window's owner doesn't chooses to ignore the closure (which it can).